# Why is my second function not returning anything?

Tags: python, function, csv

My first function gives me the desired result but the 2nd function just gives me an empty list just as I made it. But if I comment out the first function and just run the 2nd function it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv

f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

def units_by_level():
    lev1=[]
    lev2=[]
    lev3=[]
    lev4=[]
    lev5=[]
    for row in csv_f:
        if row[4]=='Level 1':
           lev1.append(row[5]) 
        if row[4]=='Level 2':
            lev2.append(row[5])
        if row[4]=='Level 3':
            lev3.append(row[5])
        if row[4]=='Level 4':
            lev4.append(row[5])
        if row[4]=='Level 5':
            lev5.append(row[5])
    return lev1,lev2,lev3,lev4,lev5   

a=units_by_level()
print("Level 1:",a[0],"Level 2:",a[1],"Level 3:",a[2],"Level 4:",a[3],"Level 5:",a[4])


def hours_by_level():
    lev1=[]
    lev2=[]
    lev3=[]
    lev4=[]
    lev5=[]
    for row in csv_f:
        if row[4]=='Level 1':
            lev1.append(row[6])

        if row[4]=='Level 2':
            lev2.append(row[6])
        if row[4]=='Level 3':
            lev3.append(row[6])
        if row[4]=='Level 4':
            lev4.append(row[6])
        if row[4]=='Level 5':
            lev5.append(row[6])
    return lev1,lev2,lev3,lev4,lev5



b=hours_by_level()
print("Level 1:",b[0],"Level 2:",b[1],"Level 3:",b[2],"Level 4:",b[3],"Level 5:",b[4])
```

Comment: @NickReed That's not how that works..

Comment: Hey guys, on the code above if i want to employ a dictionary and combine those two code together how would i go about it, also the two functions are almost identical, is there a way to add argument in the function and just make it one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your file pointer. Try this before running the 2nd function:

```
f.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

File readers don't work quite the way you think. Once you open and read through the contents of the file, you cannot automatically go over them again. So, these lines:

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
```

create a file reader that iterates over the contents of the file once. If you want to do that various times, you should probably just store the file's content in an array first, then iterate over that.